# Why does jquery.serialize change LF to CRLF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eol

I'm trying to post this form:

```
<form id="the-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <textarea class="form-control" name="list" id="list"></textarea>
</form>
```

with this script:

```
$.post( "/route", $('#the-form').serialize());
```

and debug of the script shows that `JSON.stringify($('#list').val())`

returns `"line1\nline2\nline3"`

while `$('#the-form').serialize()` returns 
`wordlist=line1%0D%0Aline2%0D%0Aline3`.

So why does *jquery.serialize* encodes `\n` to `%0D%0A`? Is there a way to make *serialize* return string with `%0A` EOL?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are encountering as a result of this? Have used `serialize()` for many years and never had issues with line breaks

Comment: thats why: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/a644101ed04d0beacea864ce805e0c4f86ba1cd1/src/serialize.js#L108 (it's programmed that way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, see [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6876):

> When serializing text, encode all line breaks as CRLF pairs per the application/x-www-form-urlencoded specification.

which [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1):

> Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').

--

> Is there a way to make serialize return string with %0A EOL?

None apart from removing `%0D`'s manually after serializing.

Answer (score 0):

As georg mentioned, this is intended functionality.

You can replace instances of `%0D%0A` in the serialized string as follows:

```
var formVars = $('#the-form').serialize().replace(/%0D%0A/g, '%0A');
```

Comment: will only replace first instance